# AWS EC2 Instance Scaling - CloudFormation/Launch Template?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-cloudformation

We currently have several groups of servers in AWS - API, WEB, CONTENT, etc. and I want to be able to scale these groups manually, not using auto scaling.

I currently create an AMI of each type of instance - de-registering and then creating a new one each day. When the need arises I would like to "click a button" to add to a particular group...for example I want to add a server to my API group:

1. It spins up a new instance based on my API_latest AMI and names it properly "API1, API2, etc."
2. It will deploy our code to make sure it has the latest for that repo
3. Then move instance into the proper Target Group/Load Balancer for use

I do not know if this type of system works as Cloudformation, Launch Templates or some amalgamation of the two or if I need to develop a custom system. The pieces that get me stuck are that we update our AMI daily (maybe not what we need) and the deploying of our code (not sure if Cloudformation allows that).

Thanks for any ideas, it is greatly appreciated. 
D

Comment: What are you adding in your incremental version of AMI ? new version of application code? And what decides it gets added to which target group? Is it dynamic? based on code deployment, because this shouldnt be step 3?

Comment: New application code. We update our code daily, and sometimes push out new code 3 to 4 times a day. It is possible that I only need a single AMI and then just update the code as indicated in step 2.

As for which target group, I am assuming I would set a parameter for the proper target group.

Comment: what about making the AMI a parameter in the Cloudformation Template, Then when you update that value it would trigger a deployment using the changed ami.

Comment: I think that is a great idea and gives me something I can work with. I think the one I am struggling the most with is step 2, having cloudformation start a deployment of code to that new instance.